# How to know if user is online/logged in with parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, authentication, chat

im creating an application to know if the user is logged in or online. So first i have a list view that the people who registered. This is my sample code

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            if (objects.size() > 0) {
                for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                    usernames.add(user.getUsername());
                }
                userListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                 // i want to add here like if(usernames.isOnline())
                 // then the image adapter of list view will change to green 
                 // instead of transparent
            }
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks very much. I want to have a list of users who is online/offline. I will appreciate every tutorial that you will tell me.

Comment: probably doesnt exists as built in.. What you can do is have timestamp of last action and if its < 1 minute the user is online.. I don't think you can do anything better than that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution by using onResume() and onDestroy

```
private void updateUserStatus(boolean online) {
    user.put("online", online);
    user.saveEventually();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    updateUserStatus(false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadUserList();
}

 public void loadUserList() {
    ParseUser.getQuery().whereNotEqualTo("username", user.getUsername())
            .findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> li, ParseException e) {
                    if (li != null) {
                        if (li.size() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "No users found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                            uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li);
                            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userListView);
                            list.setAdapter(new UserAdapter());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

And by the adapter class, the image will set off and on if the user is online or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
```

instead of the query.

Comment: I think he is trying to see a list of all his users. And want to have a connected /not connected status for them.

Comment: You're correct litelite. Thank you for explaining what i want.

Comment: On your adapter's item onBind method, compare the user with `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` and adjust the background if necessary.